# What is he meaning by saying "grab on" in a context?

Tags: word-usage

[**I was just looking our country's martial video on Youtube,**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tig31OCTzGs&lc=Ugxy4M55Q3DqNH09W8J4AaABAg.9E1_nE_qwSU9E1hsG4abDU) and the guy who has been strictly practicing the art is saying as the following. (My Youtube "logo" is TK),

He said,

> People might think this is technique from Unsu, but Shukumine only ever learnt three kata: Naihanchi, Passai and Kusanku. The kick most likely comes from Kushanku principles, but since a really big part of Gensei-ryu and Taido is based on Passai, there might be some of that in there too.

Please forget names you haven't heard because they are the name of the schools of the different Karate. (which I also don't know).

I said,

> T K
>
> You do know surprisingly very well about Tadio. Just great. I am now 46 years old but till 1 year ago I didn't know anything about Taido at all, shame.

*Taido is the martial arts you see in the video. And he responded,

> I've been training in strictly Taido for about ten years, as well as some amount of years in studying the Kishimoto katas from Seitoku Higa and Shukumine's older Gensei-ryu stuff. You'll eventually **grab on** to some stuff in that time.

By that word was he trying to say "you are going to master (learn) if you continue watching/practicing?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess would be that the speaker wanted to say [*grasp*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grasp) (look at definition 3).

Comment: "Grab" and "Grasp" are synonyms. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk00mZeIIwhcN2U0wx9ACEuWa_vC3Gg%3A1601052750272&ei=TiBuX-STEKya4-EPnb6VyAk&q=grab+meaning&oq=grab+m&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgCMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgcIABCxAxBDMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgcIABAUEIcCMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgQIABBHOgoILhDHARCvARBDUOYOWMcXYP4naABwAngAgAGHAYgB-gGSAQMwLjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to grab on a concept is to learn it (or at least bits of the concept).

You could also use the phrase "pick up on" interchangeably.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/pick%20up%20on

> 1: to have a clear idea of
>
> > The students picked up on the new material quickly.